# How to change domain of URL keeping params same using Requestly Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, domain, firefox-extensions, url-rewriting, requestly

I need to change request domain, but keep params on the same, can [Requestly](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa/) extension do it?

For Example

```
www.domain1.com?a=1&b=2 --> www.domain2.com?a=1&b=2
```

PS - The question was asked in our customer support chat. I posted it here since it is applicable in general and will help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This is very much possible using Requestly Replace Rule. Here's the steps to setup Replace Rule

1. Create New Rule
2. Select Replace Rule (Blue Color)
3. Replace `www.domain1.com` With `www.domain2.com`
4. Save Rule

Here's the screenshot of the rule

[image]

We have documentation on Replace Rule as well. [Check this out](https://www.requestly.in/blog/2018/06/16/replace-rule-documentation/). Here's an excerpt from the doc

### Switch Domains

Situation: Suppose you are working on a web app which fetches content from your REST API available at http://my-app-server.com/rules. You have cloned the API server, made some changes and running it locally on http://localhost:4000/rules. Now, you want to test your app with the new changes done on API server.

Approach1: Change the domain in your App code to hit localhost instead of my-app-server. Once your testing is done revert this change.

Approach2: Use Replace Rule Define a Replace Rule to replace http://my-app-server.comwith http://localhost:4000 in all URLs. No need to change url inside your code. After your testing, just disable the rule.